# Phpmailer add PDF attachment from a link

Tags: php, phpmailer, tcpdf

I'm using PHPMailer to send automatic email (obviously using PHP as programming language).
I would like to add a PDF attachment generated with TCPdf.
Unfortunately I cannot generate the PDF inside the php page where I'm using PHPMailer, and I cannot create a function that generate it.
I can only use a link to generate it, like this:
www.mypage.com/app-pdf/link_generate_pdf.php?IDToGenerate=131&PDFOutput=I

I was thinking that I can recall the page with the PDFOutput=S and "return" in some way the text of the PDF and add it as attachment.
Otherwise I can call the page with PDFOutput=F and save it to a temp folder and then attach it to the email.

The problem is that I don't know how to "call" a page as it were a function and return what the recalling page actually returns.

Do you have some suggestion?
Thank you

---

edit: I now understand the problem! The problem is that the URL is accessible only from autentication (login page). I thought that as I was logged in, the script was automatically capable of read the page. How can I solve this?

Comment: Use [`file_get_contents`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to save the PDF as a temp file and then attach it?

Comment: You mention using `PDFOutput=S`, did you try it? It seems like it would work.  When you use `AddStringAttachment(generatePDF.php)`

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't work, everytime blank and corrupted pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to save the file on the server first and then attach

```
file_put_contents("Tmpfile.pdf", fopen("http://example.com/file.pdf", 'r'));
```

Attach as

```
 $mail->AddAttachment('path_to_pdf/Tmpfile.pdf', $name = 'Name_of_pdf_file', 
 $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf');
```

Hope this helps

Edit: Try this. works fine over here

```
file_put_contents("path_to_pdf/Tmpfile.pdf", 
file_get_contents("http://example.com/file.pdf"));
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work, it saves every time a blank corrupted pdf. I tryed with a static pdf link and it works great. I think it doesnt work with a "generating" link.

Comment: Thank you Tunde!
After I autenticated with CURL, I used your solution and worked perfectly!