# PHPmailer pdf attachment

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm working on a form that allows user to upload multiple files (doc, pdf, jpg, png) to send to a email using PHPmailer. I have got it working with doc, jpg and png but some reason it does not work with any pdf files. Can someone tell me whats the problem?

My code:

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple">

for($ct=0;$ct<count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);$ct++) {
    $this->mailer->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$ct], $_FILES['file']['name'][$ct]);
}
```

Comment: Please tell us how it's not working with PDF files. Errors/no server found/aliens or what?

Comment: I don't know why you're having a specific problem with PDF files, but the code you posted is **unsafe**. Base your code on [the file upload example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps).

Comment: Did You try to add a mime type? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42242772/phpmailer-add-pdf-attachment-from-a-link

Comment: @Justinas, the email doesnt send at all when I try to upload pdf files to the form but email sends fine when i upload txt, jpg, doc, png files.

Comment: @ivion I have tried `$this->mailer->AddAttachment($uploadfile, $filename, $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf');.`Doesnt work.

Comment: Perhaps it isn't base64 encoded. Try for example utf-8.